# “Ils nous aideront tous”: is there an ambiguity? (the position of “tous” in a phrase)

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms, ordre-des-mots

I have a question on grammar.

I know that “*il nous aideront tous*” can mean “*they will help us all*”. (There are examples on the Internet). Can it mean “*they all will help us*”? Like in “*ils le savent tous*” (*“they all know it”*)…

I searched both this site and Google by “*the position of tous*” and variations, but I didn't find anything on the subject…

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an ambiguity,

- **Ils vont tous nous aider**  means “they will all help us”, and it's the best way to say it.
- **Tous nous aideront** is acceptable but it's formal or poetic.
- **Ils vont nous aider tous** would mean “they will help us all”, but it's a really rare use (français classique).
- **Ils nous aideront tous** can mean “they all will help us” *and* “they will help us all”, but the second one is counter-intuitive.

One particular use is without ambiguity:

- **Ils nous aideront tous autant que nous sommes**: “they will help us all, as many as we are.”

The best way to avoid any ambiguity would be :

> Ils aident **chacun d'entre nous**.
>   **Chacun d'entre eux** nous aide.

And it works with any tense.

Comment: Thank you very much, very exhaustive! May I ask a follow-up? If the tense is present (il nous aident tous), is there a way to get rid of the ambiguity for one and for the other sense? PS: I recall having encountered the word “counter-intuitive” many times, though I am not a native.

Comment: It's based on personnal experiment but, weirdly, "ils nous aident tous" wil always be understood as "they all help us" as in "ils nous viennent tous en aide".

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! (PS: l'expérience personnelle => personal experience, in this case; an experiment is something you do in physics, for example, it's one instance…)

Comment: experiment / experience I get it now, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

La phrase est ambiguë. 
"Tous" peut se rattacher à Ils (sujet) ou nous (objet direct).
Il est difficile d'expliciter des pronoms personnels, surtout lorsqu'ils sont placés avant le verbe.
Pour lever l'ambiguïté, il faut expliciter :

1) le sujet : Eux tous nous aideront. / Tous nous aideront. (meilleure
   solution  : la plus simple)/ Chacun d'entre eux nous aidera.

2) le c.o.d. : Ils nous aideront nous tous. /Ils aideront chacun d'entre
   nous  (meilleure solution) / Ils nous aideront, chacun d'entre nous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a french men : 
« il*s* nous aideront tous » can mean “they will help us all” : it's OK.

The position of tous in this case is always after the verb.
examples : Ils chantent tous ensemble (they sing all together).

Mes voisins sont gentils. Je les embrasse tous.(My neighbors are nice. I kiss them all.)

Let's see then second sentence : “they all will help us” : if you translate in french, you have ils nous aideront tous : OK

Now, Tous can be a (or a part of subject) 
examples : Mes amis sont intelligents. Tous ont réussis. (my friends are smart. all of them have succeeded.)

Tous les français boivent beaucoup de vin. (All French people drink a lot of wine).

Better example here https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/tous+savent.html   ( example with tous savent (everybody knows))

Sorry for my bad english.....

Comment: Sorry for the fact I addressed you in English, rather! And thank you for your examples.